# Reuse a property value as a variable within the same object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm sorry if my vocab is misleading in the question, but essentially I want to use a variable as the value of a property within one javascript object. For example:

```
var fruits = {
    banana: 'yellow',
    apple: 'red',
    jazz_apple: apple
}
```

If I define a function and call `this`, I can access the value no problem, i.e.

```
var fruits = {
    banana: 'yellow',
    apple: 'red',
    jazz_apple: function() {
        return this.apple //fruits.jazz_apple() returns 'red'
    }
}
```

But I don't want to define a function to get this value. Is there a way to reuse the previously declared color for `fruits.apple` ('red') on the new property `fruits.jazz_apple` within the object without a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use functions to have access to `this` (aka context).  I recommend creating a fruits function.  You can also think of the `fruits` function as a class because classes are functions in Javascript.

```
function fruits() {
    this.banana = 'yellow';
    this.apple = 'red';
    this.jazz_apple = this.apple;
}

var myFruits = new fruits();
myFruits.jazz_apple;
```

If you don't want to create a `fruits` class, you can also used variables scoped to the object.

```
function () {
    var apple = 'red',
        fruits = {
            banana: 'yellow',
            apple: apple,
            jazz_apple: apple
        };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a good way to do what you're doing without using a previously defined value, because fruits hasn't finished being created by the time you're trying to reference it.

The only reason the function  above works is because you're running it after fruits has finished being initialized.

Your best bet is adding the property after initilizing, or reusing a declared variable:

```
var fruits = {
    banana: 'yellow',
    apple: 'red'
};

fruits.jazz_apple = fruits.apple;
```

or

```
var apple_color = 'red';

var fruits = {
  banana: 'yellow',
  apple: apple_color,
  jazz_apple: apple_color
}
```